# Convert string to int in linq query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Here is the query

```
db.setupBrands.Where(x => 
    Convert.ToInt32(x.SortKey) <= id && 
    Convert.ToInt32(x.SortKey) >= desID)
.Select(x => x);
```

Here SortKey is string type i want to convert to int. On Convert.ToInt32() i got the following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Out of interest, if your `SortKey` property is always an integer, why do you have it as a string in your schema?

Comment: SortKey is String Type... @Jon Skeet

Comment: Yes, I can tell that. My point is *why*? If it's always got a numeric value, why don't you make it an integer in your schema?

Comment: Because i want to show it in 0001 form if i keep it int i will store it as 1.

Comment: @Zeb-ur-Rehman you can format integer value for displaying `String.Format("{0:0000}", value)`

Comment: Do you always want to show it as four digits? If so, store it as a number and format it later. You need to decide whether it's fundamentally a *numeric* value (in which case 1 is equal to 0001) or a *text* value (in which case they're not).

Comment: Sorry It's my requirement i can't change it. What i want is to convert value into int.

Answer (score 2):

EF can't translate Convert and Parse. I completely agree with the above, but, if your SortKey is `nchar(4)` you can try this:

```
string s_id = string.Format("{0:0000}", id);
string s_desID = string.Format("{0:0000}", desID );

db.setupBrands.Where(x => 
    x.SortKey <= s_id && 
    x.SortKey >= s_desID)
.Select(x => x);
```